# Gradle is not running after set path in environment

Tags: java, gradle, build, build.gradle

I downloaded Gradle 3.0 version and set path in environment variable.

> " C:\New_Project_Softwares\gradle3.0"

and set in the above into the path like :

> " path= %GRADLE_HOME%\bin"

. But when i run in command prompt as

> " gradle -v"

, it is saying " 'gradle' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." . This means , the path is not set properly. could you please help me out how to set path for Gradle.

Comment: check - if the path and installation is correct i.e. gradle3.0\bin exists. If thats correct then try to run the command from the bin directory. Let us know what happens.

Comment: Yeah! its working..i ran outside the gradle folder path. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
set GRADLE_HOME=C:\New_Project_Softwares\gradle3.0
set path= %GRADLE_HOME%\bin;%path%
gradle -v
```

To make sure the path is set, in command prompt type set and see in the path variable the gradle path is set.

Comment: :- i ran the above commands, But still gradle is not recognizing.

Comment: Working now. i ran the gradle command outside the gradle installed folder path. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Here is solution :

**‘gradle’ is not recognized as an internal or external command**

While trying to run a gradle command, I see ‘gradle’ is not recognized as an internal or external command. It took me sometime to know the Gradle executable path, after installing Android Studio. Hence, thought to share so it may help somebody…

The gradle executable is usually installed here(when installed by Android-Studio):

```
**<user_home_dir>.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-<version>-bins\<somekey>\gradle- 
<version>\bin**

<user_home_dir>, refers to the user directory, eg. C:Users/myuser

<version>, refers to installed gradle version number like 4.4 or 4.4.1 etc
```

the whole path looks like below

```
C:\Users\Satish\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.4- 
all\9br9xq1tocpiv8o6njlyu5op1\gradle-4.4\bin
```

[image]
    Select **Path** and click on **Edit** button

[image]

You have to set this kind of path in Environment variable PATH. And then close and reopen the cmd Prompt. Now you can able to run gradle commands

try, and you can see following details
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using same terminal(CMD), try restarting your terminal that might do the trick.
I spent an hour in that.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow their gradle docs:

https://gradle.org/install/

```
Microsoft Windows users

Create a new directory C:\Gradle with File Explorer.

Open a second File Explorer window and go to the directory where the Gradle distribution was downloaded. Double-click the ZIP archive to expose the content. Drag the content folder gradle-6.8 to your newly created C:\Gradle folder.

Alternatively you can unpack the Gradle distribution ZIP into C:\Gradle using an archiver tool of your choice.
Step 3. Configure your system environment
Linux & MacOS users

Configure your PATH environment variable to include the bin directory of the unzipped distribution, e.g.:

 $ export PATH=$PATH:/opt/gradle/gradle-6.8/bin

Microsoft Windows users

In File Explorer right-click on the This PC (or Computer) icon, then click Properties -> Advanced System Settings -> Environmental Variables.

Under System Variables select Path, then click Edit. Add an entry for C:\Gradle\gradle-6.8\bin. Click OK to save.
Step 4. Verify your installation

Open a console (or a Windows command prompt) and run gradle -v to run gradle and display the version, e.g.:

$ gradle -v

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.8
------------------------------------------------------------
```